# Android JobScheduler needs to check for working interrnet first and then run other tasks

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-jobscheduler

Ok I am using JobScheduler to sync data with a database. I know you can set requirements in JobScheduler to run a job like unmetered network  etc etc, but the problem is Jobscheduler doesnt checks if internet is working it just checks if you are connected to a network. I have 1 Job  which is periodic that has several task. I created this aync task that checks if there is internet . I want to check if the http response (StatusCode)is not equal to 200 . I want to stop the job immediately  and reschedule again. Because if Internet is not working I dont need to continue run the job. I cant figure out how to stop the job immediately and reschedule because after that async task is finished the next one begin to execute.

Here is my OnStartJob and OnStopJob

```
@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStartJob");

    new ConnectCheck(getApplicationContext(), this, jobParameters).execute();

    getRetrofitObject();
    myLocation();
    new MyToken(getApplicationContext(), this, jobParameters).execute();

    Document newMemo = new Document();


    new MyWorker(getApplicationContext(), this, jobParameters).execute(newMemo);


    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStopJob");
    return true;
}
```

Here is my Async Task

```
private static class ConnectCheck extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final MyJobService mJobService;
    private final JobParameters mJobParams;

    public ConnectCheck(Context context, MyJobService myJobService, JobParameters jobParameters) {
        mContext = context;
        mJobService = myJobService;
        mJobParams = jobParameters;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connect Check start!");
        int statusCode = 0;
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://google.com/");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpURLConnection http = null;
        try {
            http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            statusCode = http.getResponseCode();
            Log.d(TAG, "" +statusCode);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(statusCode!=200)
        {
            // reschedule a jobscheduler
            Log.d(TAG, "reschedule job");
            mJobService.jobFinished(mJobParams, true);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Boolean reschedule) {
        if (reschedule) {
            mJobService.jobFinished(mJobParams, true);
        } else {
            mJobService.jobFinished(mJobParams, false);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "ConnectCheck  finsished ------------------------");
    }
}
```

Comment: "I cant figure out how to stop the job immediately and reschedule" -- call `jobFinished()`. You seem to be doing that already if `statusCode!=200`. If your status code is 200, do your real work and calling `jobFinished()` when it is done. Then, convert this `AsyncTask` to a plain `Thread`, getting rid of `onPostExecute()`, as you do not need or want to be doing work on the main application thread here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is almost on the right path.

Remember, of the internet isn't working, the connection will time out and throw an ioexception. When it does, just set your reschedule Boolean to true and your code should call

```
jobFinished(yourparams,rescheduletrue)
```